# simple list recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of recursion and has the following queries with regard to the output of the below code:

```
def subsetsofSet(input_list, set_list=None):
    print "IN input_list: {0}".format(input_list)
    if not input_list:
        return

    input_list.pop()

    subsetsofSet(input_list)
    print "RETURN input_list: {0}".format(input_list)

subsetsofSet([1,2,3])
```

Output is as below:

```
IN input_list: [1, 2, 3]
IN input_list: [1, 2]
IN input_list: [1]
IN input_list: []
RETURN input_list: []
RETURN input_list: []
RETURN input_list: []
```

Why is the `RETURN input_list` always empty? Shouldn't it be displayed in the reverse manner of the `IN input_list`? Appreciate any help in understanding this?

Comment: You need to `return subsetsofSet(input_list)`

Comment: could you add the expected output to be and is your indentation right ?

Comment: i was expecting the output to be as below
     IN input_list: [1, 2, 3]
     IN input_list: [1, 2]
     IN input_list: [1]
     IN input_list: []
     RETURN input_list: [1]
     RETURN input_list: [1,2]
     RETURN input_list: [1,2,3]

Comment: @thefourtheye That would be true if they were actually using the return value of the function anywhere; it doesn't look like they are.

Comment: @OP The `RETURN input_list` is always empty because you recursively pop all elements from the list before any of the function calls end.

Comment: @parseltonguenewbie You are removing from the last element but why is that you are adding from the first element can you justify your output

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I do understand that I'm popping the elements of the list. But when the recursive call returns shouldn't it be returning the value of input_list in the particular stack frame for the `RETURN input_list`?

Comment: Python `list`s are objects, which means they are passed "by reference" in function parameters. `input_list` refers to the same object across all stack frames, because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is a mutable element, so you only pass a reference to the original list and it is popped on each call. If you printed the id of the list, you could see the same value.

So even if **before** calling `subsetsofSet(input_list)` for the second time the list was `[1,2]` after the return it is empty.

You should pass a copy of the list if you do not want it to be changed by recursive calls:

```
def subsetsofSet(input_list, set_list=None):
    print "IN input_list: {0}".format(input_list)
    if not input_list:
        return

    input_list.pop()

    subsetsofSet(input_list[:])
    print "RETURN input_list: {0}".format(input_list)

subsetsofSet([1,2,3])
```

Output is then:

```
IN input_list: [1, 2, 3]
IN input_list: [1, 2]
IN input_list: [1]
IN input_list: []
RETURN input_list: []
RETURN input_list: [1]
RETURN input_list: [1, 2]
```